# Apache & Nginx on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby, rvm

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with three apache virtual hosts. I just followed [this tutorial to set up Rails 3 on Ubuntu using PAssenger and nginx](http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/rails-3-on-ubuntu-10-10-with-rvm-passenger-and-nginx/).

Everything is running fine except rails/nginx. When I try to start it, I get this message:

```
* Starting Nginx Server...
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
   ...done.
```

Not sure what the problem is. Do I have to use nginx instead of apache? I'm just a novice at this point, so I'd appreciate it if any answers kept that in mind.

**Edit**

`apache2ctl -S` outputs this:

```
 default server pixelcraftwebdesign.com (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:4)
 port 80 namevhost pixelcraftwebdesign.com (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:4)
 port 80 namevhost opsandss.com (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:8)
 port 80 namevhost ergo-metric.com (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:16)
 port 80 namevhost admin.nflspot.com (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:24)
 port 80 namevhost utcmeme.com (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:29)
 port 80 namevhost ruby.pixelcraftwebdesign.com (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:37)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:*                    is a NameVirtualHost
         default server myServer (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port * namevhost myServer (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 443 namevhost myServer (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
```

Comment: Which service do you want to be used when someone connects to your server on the default port for HTTP?  It can't be both at the same time - only one can bind to port 80 (hence the error).

Comment: well, I guess apache. apache needs to point to website1.com and website2.com, but I want ruby.website1.com or website3.com to point to nginx--I JUST WANT RoR TO WORK!

Comment: I changed the listen port to 8000 and removed this error....but when I go to ruby.website1.com, I can't get my page...

Comment: Do I have to use symlinks, or is the root directive sufficient?

Comment: Huh?  How are sum links involved?  Please see my comment on the answer below.

Comment: See last step in this tutorial: http://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/05/running-rails-applications-using-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu-server.html

Comment: That's for enabling the config that you put in that file in nginx - but we're working with the Apache configuration, correct?

Comment: Both? My apache sites are working, and correctly forwards my ruby.website1.com to port 8000--which nginx should pick up?

Comment: Have you confirmed that it is forwarding the requests in Apache's logs?  Safari wouldn't display that error if Apache were working correctly and nginx were not.

Comment: Alright. Where are apache logs located? :/ I'm embarrassed to ask...

Comment: On Ubuntu, I believe it's `/var/log/apache2`

Comment: access log is empty...error log doesn't look important...

Comment: Have you restarted Apache since making the changes?  What output do you get from `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: See edit...I corrected an error.

Comment: Seems that you have extra config in the `sites-enabled` directory that you're not using - can you disable those?  Has Apache been restarted?  And are you on the same local area network as the server?

Comment: Ran `a2dissite` for those and reloaded with no errors--same problem from the browser after restarting apache...not on same network.

Comment: Can you do some debugging on the client connection?  Is the wildcard DNS resolving to the correct server?  Can you use either a web browser that gives you a more useful error message (Chrome) or do a packet capture on the HTTP connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure Apache to forward requests for the Ruby domains to nginx, which you now have listening on port 8000.

Make sure you've got a `NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere (you probably do have it in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, since you have two sites on Apache).  And enable mod_proxy (`a2enmod proxy`).  Then add this config as a new vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ruby.website1.com
    ServerAlias website3.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Awesome start! Now, I have this pointing to the name ruby.website1.com...which fails to open a page--so the problem now is with nginx's config? or perhaps my ruby installation?

Comment: In what way does it fail - do you get an HTTP error code?

Comment: Just says "Safari can't open this page." My server is setup in a way that any subdomain points to my main website.

Comment: Check Apache's logs to see if it's getting hit when you try to access it.  Are you behind the same NAT/firewall as the server?

Answer (score 1):

You have Apache occupying port 80.
If you don't move/rename Nginx 'site-enabled/default' config file (introduced recently in 1.0+) Nginx will attempt ot start on port 80 no matter what - even you specify a different listen port for Nginx.

Move/rename the file, and indicate a different port with 'listen' directive in your 'nginx.conf'.

Comment: Could you give me a little more information or examples?

Comment: Look inside '/etc/nginx/sites-available/default'. It will still have 'listen 80' inside it. Just rename the file.